# Задать время для перехода на следующий Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Подскажите, как задать время для перехода на следующий Activity. Объясню для чего.
Присвоил анимацию к кнопке которая длится 3 секунды.
Эта кнопка переводит на другой активити.
Но так как переход происходит сразу, анимацию не видно.
Вот код:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    Animation anim = null;
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.startPlayBtn:
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myrotate);
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, ChooseLvl.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    startPlayBtn.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Animation anim = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.startPlayBtn:
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChooseLvl.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myrotate);
            new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    startPlayBtn.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: Ругается на this, вот в это строке:                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChooseLvl.class);

Comment: @Michael: Как называется активити текущий? Укажите ТекущийАктивити.this

Comment: большое спасибо , всё работает

Comment: @Michael: Пожалуйста. Можно проголосовать и/или отметить ответ как правильный.